# PayPal API for "non-merchant"/private account

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

on developer.paypal.com I found out how-to register an app, get clientId and secret for this app and use the API (in my case the java api: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/)

This works fine.

BUT: I actually want to get PaymentHistory and PaymentDetails for my personal, private, non-merchant account. It is a normal enduser account which I do not want to upgrade to merchant-mode.

I am wondering how to use the API in such a scenario?
I did not found any hint to get an accessToken without registering an app.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You would use the [Classic API](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/) with standard API credentials (username, password, signature).

You can [login here](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run) to quickly obtain your API credentials.

Comment: this only redirects me to the settings page. i already confirmed my email.. Do I have to add anything before I can get my username, password and signature?

Comment: Already figured it out. You have to confirm both email address and phone number

Comment: Link to Class API is broken.